# Printing long lines in MAGMA without line break

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

In MAGMA, how do I print a long list of items to a file without automatic line breaks?  It seems to me that there is an internal length limit and anything longer than it will result in a automatic line wrap. Of course, this mess up the table that I intend to get.

A simple example is:

```
SetOutputFile("myfile"); 
print "x=\t"^20; 
UnsetOutputFile();
```

The result will not stay in one line. I tried to store the result in a string and then use the "Write" command. It gave the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [official documentation](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/49#449) the `SetColumns(n)` function allows you to set the number of columns used by the output. While the default value is 80, if $n=0$ no wrap is performed, i.e. the output will be on one line. However, this value is not taken into consideration if `AutoColumns` is set to `true`, which is by default. It can be disabled with `SetAutoColumns(false)`. Hence you can do it via

```
SetAutoColumns(false);
SetColumns(n);
```

Comment: As links can sometimes die, perhaps explain a bit what your attached link says on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem for different thing, and I will post my solution, without explanation. Maybe someone will find this useful, may be not...

```
    X:=IntegerRing(10); U:={X!1,X!3,X!7,X!9};

    for g in U do
        for h in U do
           printf "%o  ", g*h;
        end for;
        printf "\n"; 
   end for;
```